# MySQL efficient querying

Tags: mysql, database, query-performance

I am fairly new to MySQL. Considering this table:

```
 ID INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  User_name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
  Full_name VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
  User_vars VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  BirthDay DATE NOT NULL,
  password CHAR(70) NOT NULL,  
  Security_hint VARCHAR(27) NOT NULL,
  Email VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
  userType ENUM ('a','b','c','d') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a',
  Signup_Date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL  DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  activation   TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  Ip BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY User_name (User_name,Email)
```

I am using the following queries to check whether an email or user name exists in this table:

```
    $query1 ="SELECT id FROM signup WHERE Email='$Email_Input' LIMIT 1";            
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) 

$query2 = "SELECT id FROM signup WHERE User_name='$User_name' LIMIT 1";         
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

if (mysql_num_rows($result2)>0){    
echo '1';
}
else if (mysql_num_rows($result1)>0){   

echo '1';
}
```

My question: Is there an efficient way to issue just one query to check the existence of both?

Comment: `WHERE Email= AND User_name=` would be best since you also have a composed index on those columns.

Comment: I believe that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements instead of putting input value right into the query string.

Comment: All my variables hold filtered and sanitized data against XSS and SQL injections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
SELECT ID FROM signup WHERE Email ='$Email_Input' LIMIT 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT id FROM signup WHERE User_name='$User_name' LIMIT 1
```

That is, if this is two different records. If its the same record, that should answer both condtions,  simply :

```
 SELECT ID FROM signup
 WHERE Email ='$Email_Input'
   AND User_name='$User_name' 
 LIMIT 1
```